# Align image and text with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I need some help with aligning content, My image of the women needs to be aligned to the left and the text to the right.

This is a CSS Zen Garden, which means **I can only use CSS and can't edit HTML.** Is there a way to do it, without using so many margins or paddings? If i could change the HTML i would float it but here it's not possible...

I position the images with background-position: % %;

View [Alpha website](http://thomasdebelder.be/zengarden%20website/)  here

```css
/*eerste section*/

.preamble h3 {
  font-family: fraktur;
  font-size: 15em;
  color: #4A4A4A;
  margin: 5%;
}

.preamble {
  /* width: 80%; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin: 50px auto;
  /* border: 2px solid #000000; */
  background-image: url('../images/foto1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-size: contain;*/
  background-size: 40%;
  background-position: 93% 82%;
}

.preamble p {
  width: 47%;
  margin: 15px 40px;
}


/*einde eerste section*/


/*tweede section*/

.explanation h3 {
  font-family: baskerville;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 10em;
  width: 45%;
  color: #4A4A4A;
  margin: 5%;
}

.explanation {
  /* width: 80%; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin: 50px auto;
  /* border: 2px solid #000000; */
  background-image: url('../images/dame.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 93% 82%;
}

.explanation p {
  width: 47%;
  margin: 15px 40px;
}


/*einde tweede section*/
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use justify-items: end; with grid layout to move your content to the end. Then move you image to the left :)

```css
/*eerste section*/
.preamble h3 {
    font-family: fraktur;
    font-size: 15em;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    margin: 5%;
}


.preamble {
    /* width: 80%; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    margin: 50px auto;
    /* border: 2px solid #000000; */
    background-image: url('../images/foto1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-size: contain;*/
    background-size: 40%;
    background-position: 93% 82%;
}

.preamble p {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 15px 40px;
}

/*einde eerste section*/


/*tweede section*/
.explanation h3 {
    font-family: baskerville;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 10em;
    width: 45%;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    margin: 5%;
}


.explanation {
    /* width: 80%; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    margin: 50px auto;
    /* border: 2px solid #000000; */
    background-image: url('../images/dame.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 13% 82%;
    justify-items: end;
}

.explanation p {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 15px 40px;
}

/*einde tweede section*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `direction: rtl;` and `background-position: left center;`

[image]

```
.explanation {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-image: url(../images/dame.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: left center;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: direction: rtl; don't have to be use in this case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

Comment: Why not? it's a simple trick to change direction of all elements. @Lucas.S

Comment: Grid layout give you the tools to make it properly :) Don't try to use direction : rtl; to change position there, you don't need to.